# Cannot solve the error "__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" in Vector Packet processing API program

Tags: python-3.x, linux, networking

```
vpp_json_dir = '/usr/share/vpp/api/'
jsonfiles = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(vpp_json_dir):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.api.json'):
        jsonfiles.append(os.path.join(vpp_json_dir, filename))

if not jsonfiles:
    print('Error: no json api files found')
    exit(-1)
```

Code to show jsonfiles

```
vpp = VPPApiClient(jsonfiles)
```

I keep getting the error

```
    File "/home/vector/Desktop/vas/py/try3.py", line 29, in <module>
    vpp = VPPApiClient(jsonfiles)
    TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The code for the class VPPApiclient is

```
class VPPApiClient:
    """VPP interface.This class provides the APIs to VPP."""
    apidir = None
    VPPApiError = VPPApiError
    VPPRuntimeError = VPPRuntimeError
    VPPValueError = VPPValueError
    VPPNotImplementedError = VPPNotImplementedError
    VPPIOError = VPPIOError

    def __init__(self, apifiles=None, testmode=False, async_thread=True,
                 logger=None, loglevel=None,
                 read_timeout=5, use_socket=False,
                 server_address='/run/vpp/api.sock'):
```

Can someone kindly tell me on how to resolve this error?

Comment: When I search for VPPApiClient examples, I just find examples that call `VPP()`, not `VPPApiClient()`.

Comment: `vpp = VPP(jsonfiles)`

Comment: @Barmar yeah but if I run the code it says VPP does not exist as actually you might have noticed documentation is a bit old the latest version does not have any class as VPP

Comment: Is that the full backtrace?

Comment: Yes sir it's the full back trace

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

`vpp=VPP(apifiles=jsonfiles)`